# Spring Boot 2 - Change Jar Name

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using Spring Boot 2 in my Gradle project to do a build to jar in Jenkins, and I would like to change the name of that jar file.

By default, Spring Boot 2 used the Gradle property `rootProject.name`, which can be set in the `/settings.gradle` file.

However, I would like to change the jar file name, without changing the `rootProject.name`.

Here are my `bootJar` and `springBoot` sections of the `build.gradle` file:

```
bootJar {
  launchScript()
}
```

.

```
springBoot {
  buildInfo {
    properties {
      artifact = "jarName"
      group = "groupName"
      name = "projectName"
      version = "1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** `artifact` is not setting the jar name, as I expected it to, after reading: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator

Comment: The `artifact` build info property is, by default, derived from the base name of the `bootJar` or `bootWar` task not the other way around. If you configure it explicitly, the base name-based default will no longer be used and the explicit value will be used instead. The base name of the `bootJar` or `bootWar` task will be unaffected.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: Thanks! Removing `springBoot.buildInfo.properties.artifact` and adding `bootJar.baseName` worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [@AndyWilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) for the answer!

```
bootJar {
  baseName "jarName"
  launchScript()
}
```

.

```
springBoot {
  buildInfo {
    properties {
      group = "groupName"
      name = "projectName"
      version = "1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 73):

`archiveFileName` is the new hotness. Everything else is deprecated.

```
bootJar {
   archiveFileName = "${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
}
```

or the Kotlin DSL equivalent:

```
tasks.getByName<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar>("bootJar") {
   this.archiveFileName.set("${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}")
}
```

See:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html

Comment: I was looking for the secret sauce to manipulate the template. As I am not a seasoned gradle handler, I forgot you have to `get()` the values. This is the answer for those who wish to have FULL control over the build name

Comment: Why is the `get()` necessary? Without it Gradles generate the name with the command output.

Answer (score 14):

Since [`bootJar`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJar.java) tasks extends `Jar` you can use `archiveName` to set name the directly:

```
bootJar {
   archiveName = 'whatever'
}
```

Have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName).

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, as well as `jar{baseName 'whatever'}` and neither worked. (I think those only worked in SpringBoot 1.)

Comment: This is almost right. The task that's customized needs to be `bootJar` rather than `jar` though. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use:

```
tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
}
```

Or with the jar-plugin

```
tasks.jar {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

My goal was to remove version from the archive name. I did it this way:

```
bootJar {
   archiveName = "$baseName.$extension"
}
```

Now Gradle generates "project-name.jar" instead of "project-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". This solution is general and doesn't hardcode any particular archive name.

Comment: The [archiveName](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName) property is deprecated for some reason, but I found a simplier approach: `bootJar { archiveVersion = null }`. This overrides default value of [archiveVersion](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveVersion) property, which is equal to `project.version` by default. Jar task generates the final `archiveFileName` without version in this case.

Answer (score 8):

**For Gradle 6**

```
bootJar {
    archiveBaseName = 'freeway-server'
    archiveVersion = '1.0.0'
    archiveFileName = 'freeway-server.jar'
}
```

**For get:-**

```
System.out.print(bootJar.getArchiveBaseName().get())
System.out.print(bootJar.getArchiveVersion().get())
System.out.print(bootJar.getArchiveFileName().get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people simply want to not have the version in the jar name, not change the name completely.

```
tasks.withType<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar> {
    archiveVersion.set("")
}
```

will do it using Kotlin DSL. The final name is given by `tasks.bootJar.get().archiveFileName.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

For me worked

```
project(':org.awseome.subproject') {
 jar() {
     archiveFileName = 'nameOfJar.jar'
 }
}
```

inside of main build.gradle. Used

Gradle 6.X
Spring Boot 2.X