# Create jar with fix name excluding version using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I want to create a `fat jar` using `gradle` only with name, not include a version of the project.

I am using `gradle 5.1` and `spring boot 2.1.1`.

I have tried the following solutions with no luck

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123771/8123983
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407245/8123983

   - Default jar name `project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
   - Expected jar name `project-xyz.jar`

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution, finally!

`jar {
    archivesBaseName="project-name"
    project.version=""
}`

I have also tried with `version` instead of `project.version`. But, it's not working anymore in gradle 5.1 as it is deprecated as per the documentation.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:version

`archivesBaseName` changes only the prefix name, not remove the version from the jar name.

Comment: Hi S_K, this solution works also for me for the jar-name, but has the disadvantage that the gradle project.version is set to empty also for other gradle tasks, which can lead to other problems. Therefore it worked better for me to just set archiveFileName="" like also mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

On an example of Spring Boot 2.4+ && Gradle 6+,
modify *build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0.RELEASE'
}

bootJar {
    archiveFileName = 'flawless-application.jar'
}
```

without boot plugin

```
jar {
    archiveFileName = 'flawless-application.jar'
}
```

More docs here:

1. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html
2. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName
3. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable